# Convert Similarity Score Matrix to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a similarity matrix stored in numpy array that looks like this

[Numpy Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElDUw.png)

What is the most efficient way to convert them to a dataframe that looks like this?

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Loz.png)

This is my current code but I don't think it is the most efficient.

```
sim_npy = np.load('sim.npy')
row=0
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        df_tsc.loc[row] = list(np.array(['Item'+str(i), 'Item'+str(j),str(sim_npy[i][j])]))
        row = row + 1
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?

Comment: Specifically, the code to get to the similarity matrix would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy for improve performance:

```
a = np.array([[1,0.3,0.5],[0.3,1,0.7],[0.5, 0.7,1]])
print (a)
[[1.  0.3 0.5]
 [0.3 1.  0.7]
 [0.5 0.7 1. ]]

#upper triangle part includes the diagonal
idx = np.triu_indices(a.shape[0], k = 0)

#repeat range and filter by indices
c = np.repeat(np.arange(1, a.shape[0]+1), a.shape[0]).reshape(a.shape)[idx]
i = np.tile(np.arange(1, a.shape[0]+1), a.shape[0]).reshape(a.shape)[idx]
#filter array by indices
v = a[idx]

#create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Source':c, 'Destination': i, 'Similarity_Score': v})
#add substring
df[['Source','Destination']] = 'Item'+df[['Source','Destination']].astype(str)
print (df)
  Source Destination  Similarity_Score
0  Item1       Item1               1.0
1  Item1       Item2               0.3
2  Item1       Item3               0.5
3  Item2       Item2               1.0
4  Item2       Item3               0.7
5  Item3       Item3               1.0
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this.  What if need the lower triangle part as well? i.e. similarity of Item1->Item2 is not the same as Item2->Item1.

Comment: But my answer do it exactly.

Comment: For eg, I also need Source=Item2 and Dest=Item1. Anyway, I've figured it out by repeating your codes using np.tril_indices and concat both DFs. Thanks, jezrael. I learnt a lot from you. :)